# ObjectMapper is trying to parse string as json instead of xml

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

I am trying to parse XML in spring boot test with custom deserializer.

```
@SpringBootTest
public class MyTest {

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper mapper;

    @Test
    public void shouldParseXmlString() {
        final String input = "<abc>value</abc>"  // Some XML string which is valid xml
        MyClass myClass = mapper.readValue(input, MyClass.class);
        assertEquals("value", myClass.getAbc());
    }
}
```

I have a custom deserializer which extends `JsonDeserializer<MyClass>` and deserialize xml to `MyClass`. When I use `XmlMapper` directly instread of injecting it it works well, however when I am trying to inject `ObjectMapper` in test it fails with following error.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)) expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
```

As the error indicates, it is trying to parse the input string as json instead of xml. How can I parse the xml by injecting either `ObjectMapper` or `XmlMapper`?

In `pom.xml` I have added `jackson-core` and `jackson-dataformat-xml` as dependencies of version 2.10.0

Comment: did the answer help?

Answer (score 0):

Autowiring `ObjectMapper` would just autowire `ObjectMapper` bean by type. What you are expecting is to inject XmlMapper to variable of type `ObjectMapper`. Assuming you have a `XmlMapper` bean defined like

```
@Bean
public XmlMapper xmlMapper(){
    return new XmlMapper();
}
```

you can inject it to `ObjectMapper` variable by name

```
@Qualifier("xmlMapper")
@Autowired
private ObjectMapper mapper;
```

Comment: This is not working for me since I need to inject dependencies in custom deserializer and when you do `new XmlMapper()` spring boot won't inject the dependencies.

Comment: you just need to inject the right bean. Where have you defined bean of `XmlMapper`?

Comment: I think should not have to define it separately since spring provide first class support for jackson the bean which can deserialize xml should be already available. I can get `ObjectMapper` injected without defining it but not `XmlMapper` since spring doesn't expose `XmlMapper` as bean. So I am looking for correct way to get the bean injected which can deserialize xml without really need to define it explicitly.